# Versioning issue : Geolocator is not working on 2.14

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eSOm.png)

How can i fix the versioning issue ?

Answer (score 0):

As it says, you need to upgrade dart SDK to the latest version by running the command `flutter upgrade`. Make sure to backup your project

Comment: but i need 2.5.3 and upgrade takes the version to 3.x.x

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator_windows/versions  only depends on 2.15. You can manually upgrade flutter version has includes Dart SDK 2.15.

Comment: is it can be an issue of mac m1 ?=

Comment: If you are using this package https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator_windows/versions then i can say that it'll behave differently on mac. Because this package is specific for windows platform.